# How can I add records in my database generically?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am trying to add an object to the database regardless of the properties in the object. For example I have these two class, each goes in its own table.

```
class Movie { 
    public $Id;
    public $Name;
    public $PegiRating;
    public $Length;
}

 class Location {
    public $Id;
    public $Street;
    public $HouseNumber;
    public $City;
    public $PostalCode;
    public $Telephone;
    public $Email;
}
```

The problem that is that this has to be in a prepared statement. I already managed to get the correct sql query but I failed to get the values in.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static function addRecord($tableName, $object)
{
    //Creates an array of the object and removes the Id.
    $object = (Array)$object;
    unset($object["Id"]);

    //Initializing variables
    $columnNames = Array();
    $values = Array();
    $amountOfQuestionmarks = 0;
    $columns = "";
    $questionmarks = "";

    //Setting variables
    foreach ($object as $column => $value) {
        $amountOfQuestionmarks++;
        array_push($values, $value);
        array_push($columnNames, $column);
    }

    //Setting the strings
    for($i=0;$i <$amountOfQuestionmarks;$i++){
        $columns .= $i != 0? ", $columnNames[$i]" : $columnNames[$i];
        $questionmarks .= $i != 0? ", ?" : "?";
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($columns) VALUES ($questionmarks)";

    $db = Db::getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    for($i = 0; $i < $amountOfQuestionmarks;$i++){
        $stmt->bind_param($i+1, $values[$i]);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $db->close();
}
```

In the last for loop, I am trying to bind the value, but this fails. So my question is how can I bind the values to the prepared statement.

Comment: Any error messages? "This fails" is a bit generic.

Comment: @Michel Yes there is: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\Security\Classes\Db.php on line 140`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the syntax for bind_param at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Not bind_param(index,var)

Its bind_param(string of types, var1, var2, var3,...., Varn);

And use pdo its more portable

Comment: I think I will change everything to pdo. There was somebody who solved with pdo and I believe pdo was better then mysqli (still reading into pdo).

Comment: Its easier said than done especially if you didn't build the system, but if you're starting from scratch, its like flying without wings, mysqli will make it harder to switch to another database provider, having a system dependent on a specific suite of application protocols

Answer (score -1):

It fails because you need to use [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) instead of bind_param. It works fine otherwise.

Comment: This will result in the following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Security\Classes\Db.php:140 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Security\Api\Test\index.php(14): Db::addRecord('prices', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Security\Classes\Db.php on line 140`. Do I have to add something?

Comment: OP uses mysqli, not PDO

Comment: I will leave my response if it helps you, otherwise tell me to delete it since it is irrelevant to the actual question

Comment: I did help me in realizing that it is better to use pdo than mysqli.